# The collection of mean value abscissas in the Mean value theorem

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, mean-value-theorem

The integral mean value theorem for continuous f on [0,b] and finite positive continuous measure $\mu$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\mu[a,b]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\mu(x)=f(c)(*)$$
for at least one $c\in [a,b]$. We want to study the properties of such $r\in C_{f,a,b}:=\{c: c \text{ that satisfy (*)} \}=f^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{\mu[a,b]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\mu(x)\big)$.

In our particular problem, we want to compare to it a different $c'$ from
$$\frac{1}{\mu[0,a]}\int_{0}^{a}f(x)d\mu(x)=f(c')$$, by estimating their difference from below:
$$c-c'>\delta.$$
(Our f is positive continuous but nondifferentiable and non-monotone and so we cannot simply invert).

> Q1: How to express the condition $c-c'>\delta$ in terms of properties of f and $\mu$? What are some distinct requirements on $f,\mu$ for this lower bound to be true? Conversely, suppose that the MVT set is contained within a small neighbourhood $C_{f,a,b}\subset [x_{0}-\epsilon,x_{0}+\epsilon]$. What does that imply for the behaviour of f (at least when $\mu=$Lebesgue)?
>
> Q2: But I am curious if there is a framework for studying the properties of $C_{f,a,b}$? Is there any literature out there on putting bounds on the inf and sup of this set for various types of functions?
>
> Q3: A geometric interpretation for such c is as the values that give matchings area in (*). I am curious if there have been any more theoretical results using that idea. Maybe studying some minimization problem:
> $$arginf\{|\frac{1}{\mu[a,b]}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)d\mu(x)-f(r)|^{2}\}$$
> using some optimization algorithm.
> [image] (from MVT's wiki)

1. If $|c-c'|\leq \delta$ for all $c\in C_{f,a,b},c'\in C_{f,0,a}$ then by the geometric interpretation and the Second-MVT, we intuitively see that the function must be like a trapezoid reaching a plateau inside the $\delta-$neighbourhood of $x=a$. Inside that plateau f must have a few high peaks that have enough area underneath them to give a mean value equality. This is assuming we work with $\mu$ Lebesgue; for more general measures, we can get different shapes.
2. Some work on exploring this same reverse question: given c what can we say about f: ["On Functions Whose Mean Value Abscissas Are Midpoints, with Connections to Harmonic Functions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02558) and ["When Are There Continuous Choices for the Mean Value Abscissa?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02026).
3. [Partial Converse to the mean value theorem](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/002073902753586373)